# Потокобезопасный Singleton без synchronize

Tags: java

Самая популярная реализация данного поттерна выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class BillPughSingleton {

  private BillPughSingleton(){}

  private static class SingletonHelper{
    private static final BillPughSingleton INSTANCE = new BillPughSingleton();
  }

  public static BillPughSingleton getInstance(){
    return SingletonHelper.INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

Данный вариант обладает ленивой инициализацией, но вот никак не пойму, что делает его потокобезопасным, тут же нет никаких `volatile` и `synchronize`... Не могли бы вы пояснить ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сам я из .NET-ого мира, но могу предположить, что идея похожая.

В этом случае потокобезопасным синглтон должна делать среда выполнения, которая должна **гарантировать**, что инициализатор класса будет работать безопасно в многопоточной среде (а это значит, что во время выполнения инициализатора будет захвачена некоторая блокировка, которая и даст эту гарантию).

Вот похожий вопрос на большом SO: [Are Java static initializers thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878577/are-java-static-initializers-thread-safe)

> Yes, Java static initializers are thread safe (use your first option).
>
> However, if you want to ensure that the code is executed exactly once
>   you need to make sure that the class is only loaded by a single
>   class-loader. Static initialization is performed once per
>   class-loader.